# OpenCV finding contour of not connected points set (in other words: in black and white image with uncontinuous edges)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I've been working on image recognition of screws and have trouble with finding a "clean" contours for them (at least for something more universal than global thresholding). [I think I'm getting close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsg1v.png) but can't quite put my finger on last step- how to extract those contours (that I see but that aren't really there yet for contour-finding algorithms).

I've been trying to dilate/erode this picture but eroding it any further removes too much information and by dilating I get a lot of noise which slows down later computation.

So far my code looks like this (C++):

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("ROI.jpg"); //load image http://imgur.com/a/Y15T2
cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY); //convert it to grayscale
GaussianBlur(image, image, Size(5, 5), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT); //blur
    //find laplacian
    Laplacian(image, image, CV_16S, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT); 
    convertScaleAbs(image, image);
cv::threshold(image, image, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY + THRESH_OTSU); //use Otsu's thresholding to convert it to binary image
erode(image, image, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(), 1); //erode once
```

I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you please post the original image.

Comment: Sure (it's in code's comments btw): http://imgur.com/a/Y15T2